# CGit on Nginx do not show repository content

Tags: git, nginx, cgit

I configured `cgit` on `nginx` with this [guide](http://russellhaering.com/2009/12/22/running-cgit-under-nginx/). In result, I can see list of repositories, but when I click to view on of them, I am back on main page. You cat take a look here: [problem_here](http://kaction.name). Nginx logs says nothing useful. How can I debug problem?

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems to be working with me.., can you paste a non working link